# Proxy webpack-dev-server from the DOM

Tags: fetch, webpack-dev-server

I want to add a fetch call to the initial load of `index.html` on a local app. This data is otherwise loaded server-side, but for this particular case I need to make an http call in dev.

I am having difficulty proxying the webpack-dev-server with the fetch added to the DOM.

The proxy **is working correctly** after my app is instantiated and I use Axios to make http calls to `/api`, but on init, the proxy is still serving from localhost instead of the target endpoint.

This is a bit puzzling to me - why might the proxy work in JS post-load but not on init?

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: '/some/path',
    port: 9000,
    https: true,
    open: true,
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    proxy: { '/api/*': [Object] }
  },
```

Script in index

```
  <script>
      (async function() {
        const data = await getData();
        addDataset(data);

        async function getData() {
          return fetch('/api/my/endpoint').then(
            (response) => response.data.result,
          );
        }

        function addDataset(data) {
          var el = document.getElementById('root');
          const parsed = JSON.parse(data);
          Object.entries(parsed).forEach((entry) => {
            const [k, val] = entry;
            el.dataset[k] = JSON.stringify(val);
          });
        }
      })();
    </script>
```

Error

```
400 Bad request 
Request URL - https://localhost:9000/api/my/endpoint
```

Comment: I've seen you got 400 error (bad request)! Did you call the api correctly?

Comment: So far as I can tell, yes. The `/api` is the same prefix in the code that I currently have in the `fetch` call in the script listed above

Comment: Is your project public? Can I have a look at this? I can help you out.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not. This is for a React app which is deployed to an enterprise server with a convoluted script hosting path, so between the  webpack proxy + the custom webpack config I am sure that I overlooked something. That said, I will try to pull out the actual config into a reasonable format.